# My iPhone 4 won't send text messages!

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

My iPhone is not sending text messages through. It will take a long time to send (progressing the little bar at top very slowly), then it says "Message not Delivered". Why and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I have had this issue when I use certain people's wi-fi; however, in the case of cellular I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have functional internet connectivity?
Do you receive texts?
Did your Apple ID change?

Comment: Could be your sim card, you can check if that is the problem at a telecom provider

Comment: 1. Does it work with some people and not others? 2. Have you tried rebooting your phone?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, there are two things you can try:

- It is possible that your carrier's network is having problems. The best course of action is to see whether the problem goes away after a day or two
- Have the person you are trying to message send you a message to your phone and reply then to see whether this fixes the connection issues